Rotman-Homological Algebra Theorem 6.32
I am reading Rotman's "An Introduction to Homological Algebra" and am stuck on the proof of Theorem 6.32 (page 355-356):


I do not understand why the equalities $W = \text{Tor}_1(K_{i-1}, V_{j-1})$, $X = \text{Tor}_1(K_{i-1}, V_j)$, etc. hold. For $\text{Tor}_1(K_{i-1}, V_{j-1})$ for instance, I know we can take $\to P_{i+2} \to P_{i+1} \to P_i \to K_{i-1} \to 0$ to be a projective resolution of $K_{i-1}$, but I don't see how the first homology group upon applying $- \otimes V_{j-1}$ is isomorphic to W.

To compute $\operatorname{Tor}_1$, you need to find a resolution of $K_{i-1}$. But you already have one: $\{P_{a}\}_{a > i}$. The following sequence is not exact, but $\operatorname{Tor}_1(K_{i-1}, V_{j-1})$ is the homology at $P_{i+1} \otimes V_{j-1}$.
$$
P_{i+2} \otimes V_{j-1} \longrightarrow  P_{i+1} \otimes V_{j-1} \longrightarrow P_i \otimes V_{j-1} \longrightarrow K_{i-1} \otimes V_{j-1} \longrightarrow 0
$$
Since $P_{i+2} \longrightarrow K_{i+1}$ is surjective,
$$
\operatorname{im}(P_{i+2} \otimes V_{j-1} \longrightarrow P_{i+1} \otimes V_{j-1}) = \operatorname{im}(K_{i+1} \otimes V_{j-1} \longrightarrow P_{i+1} \otimes V_{j-1}) \\ = \ker(P_{i+1} \otimes V_{j-1} \longrightarrow K_{i} \otimes V_{j-1}).
$$
The second equality comes from the exact sequence $0 \longrightarrow K_{i+1} \longrightarrow P_{i+1} \longrightarrow K_i \longrightarrow 0$.
Therefore,
$$
\operatorname{Tor}_1(K_{i-1}, V_{j-1}) = \ker(P_{i+1} \otimes V_{j-1} \longrightarrow P_i \otimes V_{j-1}) / \operatorname{im}(P_{i+2} \otimes V_{j-1} \longrightarrow P_{i+1} \otimes V_{j-1}) \\
= \ker(P_{i+1} \otimes V_{j-1} \longrightarrow P_i \otimes V_{j-1}) / \ker(P_{i+1} \otimes V_{j-1} \longrightarrow K_{i} \otimes V_{j-1}) \\
\cong \ker(K_{i} \otimes V_{j-1} \longrightarrow P_{i+1} \otimes V_{j-1})
$$
The last isomorphism should be easy to obtain handling the morphisms between 3 objects.
